# .info/serverTimeOffset for Firestore?

Tags: firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database, synchronization, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore and want to get a rough idea of the the server time. Similar to how the [Realtime Database had .info/serverTimeOffset](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities?update_high_contrast=true&authuser=0). I could create a realtime database just to use the .info/serverTimeOffset endpoint but is there any better way using just Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `.info/serverTimeOffset` in Cloud Firestore at the moment. That's one of the reasons we recommend [using the Firebase Realtime Database for a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence), even when you use Cloud Firestore for other data storage needs.